# Do I need a transit visa to travel to USA from India, if I already have a F1 visa?

Tags: usa, transit, indian-citizens, f1-visas

I have a valid F1 visa (student) stamped in my Indian passport. I am traveling from India to USA with a connection in Doha. Doha doesn't need a transit visa, but Chicago does - as per the travel website. I have to catch another connection from Chicago to another state and this is where the transit visa is marked as required.

Do I really need this, if I have a valid visa marked in my passport?

Edit: As we all suspected, a transit-visa is not required. They agency guys are slow learners, as it turns out.

Comment: Chicago is part of the USA! So if you can enter the USA, what's the problem?

Comment: I know right! but the websites tells me so

Comment: Your itinerary ends in the US, so this doesn't make any sense. You simply clear immigration in Chicago and then go wherever you are going.

Comment: What weird website was it that told you this?

Comment: It is indeed a crappy site called 'yatra.com'

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need a transit visa. A transit visa is to allow you to temporarily enter a country, for example, to change planes. You already have a visa that allows you to enter the USA so you don't need another one just because you're changing planes.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a valid USA Visa, just board the flight ending in any USA port and enter the country answering Immigration officers there.

If your place of study is not Chicago, they may ask you why you chose to come here first. When you give proper answers for your travel and study plans, nothing else to worry about.

Best luck and Bon Voyage